# How to use has_key? method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to check if a key 'test' is include or not in a hash with rails. I tried `has_key?`('test') method but following error occur.

> undefined method `has_key?'

How to check if key is include or not? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `has_key?` is defined on `Hash` in standard Ruby (not Rails), and should work. If you're getting "undefined method", check if your object is really a `Hash`.

Comment: as @Amadan said, try to `put` the class of the object to make sure it is a hash. ex: `'name'.class` will return `String`

Answer (score 3):

```
h = {a:1, b:2, c:3}

h.has_key? :a

=>true
```

This should work in rails. There must be another issue with your code. Please share it.